# Nextjs Google Oauth2 invalid_grant error Gaxios

Tags: javascript, next.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

Trying to authenticate with googleapis oauth client.

Getting the following error:

```
 ⨯ node_modules/.pnpm/gaxios@6.1.1/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js (141:22) @ Gaxios._request
 ⨯ Error: invalid_grant
    at setCredentials
```

The weird part is this only happens when I call the set credentials method on the client

I am able to get a valid token response. Here's my code:

```
export const generateUrl = async (): Promise<string> => {
  const url = sheets.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: googleSheetsScopes,
  })
  console.log("url", url)
  return url
}

export const setCredentials = async (code: string): Promise<void> => {
  const user = await currentUser()
  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("Not logged in")
  }
  const { tokens } = await sheets.getToken(code)

  try {
    console.log("tokens", tokens)
    sheets.setCredentials(tokens) ==> error here
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("e", e)
  }
}
```

I get a valid token when I log tokens to the console:

```
tokens {
  access_token: '****',
  refresh_token: '****',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expiry_date: 1704909622185
}
```